# How to count events after set date with COUNTIFS?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

I'm creating this report in spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U48MybVshKT3eRYE9goRCab9k1KCoXe7Zsr9Ogkkm4Y/edit?usp=sharing

In "BD" you can find the records and in "NB-month" the KPI that I want to analyze; I would like to create DATE filter for the numbers in the columns, ex for the col: "nº Contract closed" I'm thinking to use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(BD!R:R;A5;BD!G:G;">"&DATE(B2))
```

but I get a value: "0" that is incorrect because for this agent "Carla Vaello" the number of contracts closed after 2020-02-01 should be "2".

Answer (score 1):

your usage of `DATE` formula is wrong (`DATE` requires 3 parameters). either change `DATE` to `DATEVALUE` or use:

```
=COUNTIFS(BD!R:R; A5; BD!G:G; ">"&B2)
```

[image: 0]